# AVG using specific condition for each row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, ssms

I have a `Quotation` table with `QuotationID, ClientID` field.
A `QuotationDetail` table with `QuotationID, ProductID`
A `Sales` table with `Year, ProductID, ClientID and Quantity`.

I'm trying to create a view with the following columns:
`QuotationID` | `Client Name` | `Product Name` | `Quantity2015` | `Quantity2016`

I am able to join the quotations table with clients and products but can't figure out how to SUM Quantity values for each view row filtering by YEAR (2015 and 2016).

PS: I did not specify but I have the Clients and Products tables with the fields I mentioned.

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Actual table creation, sample data, and expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
Quantity2015 = SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2015 THEN QuantityTotal ELSE 0 END)
Quantity2016 = SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2016 THEN QUantityTotal ELSE 0 END)
```

Not very flexible, but it does work.  You can use other aggregators than SUM as well.

Ok, so a full query example would look like this.  You might need to correct table names (especially for Client/Product).

```
SELECT Q.QuotationId
    , C.ClientName
    , P.ProductName
    , Quantity2015 = SUM(CASE WHEN S.[Year] = 2015 THEN S.Quantity ELSE 0 END)
    , Quantity2016 = SUM(CASE WHEN S.[Year] = 2016 THEN S.Quantity ELSE 0 END)
FROM Quotation AS Q
    INNER JOIN Client AS C ON C.ClientID = Q.ClientID
    INNER JOIN QuotationDetail AS QD ON QD.QuotationID = Q.QuotationID 
    INNER JOIN Product AS P ON P.ProductID = QD.ProductID
    INNER JOIN Sales AS S ON S.ProductID = QD.ProductID AND S.ClientID = Q.ClientID 
GROUP BY Q.QuotationId
    , C.ClientName
    , P.ProductName
```